# How can I create an abstract base class in C++?

Tags: c#, c++, polymorphism, virtual, abstract

How would I go about doing the following in C++ (the following code is C#):

```
class Base
{
    public virtual void Foo()
    {
        // do stuff...
    }
}

class C : Base
{
    public override void Foo()
    {
        base.Foo(); // <=== how do you do this line?
    }
}
```

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a code translation service](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129362). Explain the requirements in plain English, not in code in another programming language.

Comment: Try `Base::Foo();` in the derived class's `Foo`

Comment: This code doesn't compile in C# "Cannot call an abstract base member".

Comment: Richard - post your C++ code so far to avoid boilerplate 'slap on wrist'

Comment: Foo is probably not abstract in Base, you wouldn't be able to call it otherwise...

Comment: @SteveTownsend are you talking to me? Not quite sure what you are referring to.

Comment: My post's code has changed from what I typed...

Comment: You don't call an abstract base method, it simply can't work...

Comment: You cannot provide an implementation for an abstract method in C#, and if you remove the implementation you get to the exact error example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664435%28v=vs.71%29.aspx. Maybe you did not mean `abstract` but `virtual` in the base class's method?

Comment: I did indeed mean virtual, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use operator `::`:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base() {}
    virtual void Foo()
    {
        // do stuff
    }
};

class C : public Base
{
public:
    void Foo()
    {
        Base::Foo();
    }
};
```

To have an abstract class in C++ at least one method needs to be pure virtual:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base() {}
    virtual void Foo() {}
    virtual void another_function() = 0; // Pure virtual function.
};
```

Comment: `Base::Foo` is supposed to be abstract, so OP can't "do stuff" there. Make it a pure virtual function. Of course, the consequence of that would be that `Base::Foo()` makes no sense anymore.

Comment: @Branko A pure virtual function can have an implementation, too.

Comment: Perfect, the :: operator was exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: @rhughes except that this doesn't give you what you were asking for, which doesn't make sense in C++.

Comment: @juanchopanza if you look at my original (pre altered by somebody else) code, it answers by question perfectly :)

Comment: @rhughes I did, I think you always had the abstract base class concept going on.

Comment: Maybe the way I explained it wasn't clear enough - but its all good now

Comment: @jrok Ahh... I keep forgetting these C++ idiosyncrasies :(

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
class base {
public:
    virtual void Foo() = 0;
}

class sub : public base {
public:
    void Foo() { 
        std::cout << "In Sub!" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Notice the use of the `virtual` keyword. In C++, unless explicitly declared, function implementations are not looked up at runtime, like C#, Objective-C or Java. Thus, we must tell the runtime that

'Hey, we have a function over here that needs to have it's implementation determined at runtime, so don't assume that it's of a class `base`, but of a subclass.'

Also note the `= 0` part of the function declaration. In C++, this describes a `pure  virtual` function. Without it, `base` cannot be abstract, unless there is another function that is said to be `pure virtual` in the class.

Comment: My comment on the q was for OP. sorry for confusion

Comment: In C#, virtualness is very much explicit, like in C++, but unlike Java .

Comment: @Fanael not in the same way as C++. I can override a method in C#, cast the subclass to the base class, and when I call the method on the base class, It will call the subclass implementation. That isn't possible in C++

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: I can override a method in C++, cast the subclass to a reference to the base class, and when I call the method on the base class, it will call the subclass implementation. Actually, my point was that in C#, a method is not virtual unless explicitly marked so - just like in C++.

Answer (score 1):

I would just like to point out that **you can**  do this in C++. You just implement the pure virtual function in C++ that is you can do this in your .h:

```
class Base
{
    public:
       Base();
       virtual ~Base();
       virtual void Foo()=0;
};
```

and this in your .cpp

```
void Base::Foo()
{
   std::cout<< "In Base::Foo which is pure virtual\n";
}
```

Then in your derived class do what the others have indicated and in your Derived::Foo() you can call Base::Foo() which will produce output.  Making a function pure virtual does not obviate its a ability to have executable code.

Answer (score 0):

To make a class abstract in C++, you need to provide it with a pure virtual function.  The C++ version of your code would be:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void Foo() = 0; //setting a virtual function to 0 makes it pure virtual.     This is abstract.
}

class C : Base
{
public:
    void Foo()
    {
        Base::Foo(); //I don't think this line will work...You're calling an abstract method.
    }
}
```